# React/RCTBlobManager.h file not found in react-native-pdf issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-pdf

My React Native version is 0.60.5 . I tried to installed react-native-view-pdf library .While Building Xcode it is throwing error says "React/RCTBlobManager.h file not found in **react-native-pdf** issue"

Answer (score 2):

In your RCTPdfView.m file change the line "React/RCTBlobManager.h" with this

```
#if __has_include("RCTBlobManager.h")
  #import "RCTBlobManager.h"
#else
 #import <React/RCTBlobManager.h>
#endif
```

and delete your application in simulator if exist, then run your project again. I hope it works!